# ColdFusion - I'm not familiar with this application

Tags: apache-flex, coldfusion, flexbuilder, web-standards

My boss passed away suddenly, leaving behind little in notes and information and didn't share much with me while I worked with him.  He'd been here for 29 years and so took a lot of information with him.

One of the items he had here is a ColdFusion server v9 and a lot of apps that he had written that our users rely on.  He loved to write code, 5 different languages I've found so far, me not so much, I know a little.  My question is......to keep his apps going ,until I can find replacements for them, is there a web content editing software to go with a ColdFusion server or am I just going to have to pull the plug on his apps when they break?

I found an Adobe Flex Builder 2 CD and an Adobe Creative Suite 3 Web Standard CD.  Of any value to me?  Looks like they are old versions. With 250 users and equipment, network, etc to take care of I'm a little busy.  Any information on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're talking about a text editor where you can change code, you'll probably want to go with Sublime 2. Sublime 3 is out but not totally error-free, and you have to manually downloaded the ColdFusion package for text highlighting. Sublime (all versions) is free to download. ColdFusion itself is easy enough that you could learn it, or find someone to learn it, within a week or two. It's the hooked-on-phonics of web programming. However, StackOverflow is meant for specific, programmatic questions. You may find better resources elsewhere. Best of luck and I'm sorry you're in this situation.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.learncfinaweek.com/ this is an informative website about Coldfusion. Very simple to understand. Also I use Sublime text 2 or 3 for Coldfusion development. Hope that helps. You can also use Coldfusion builder or any other editor you may prefer.

Comment: Thank you TRose.  I found sublime2 on his computer.  Must be how he did his code writing.  I'll see if I can go from there.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you osekmedia.  I will check out that site.  I found sublime 2 on his computer so learning more as we go.  Thanks again!

Comment: Did you check your boss's machine to see what he had installed?  Maybe you can keep that machine hooked up to your network and remote in when necessary.

Comment: Thanks Dan,  I am using his computer so no problem keeping it hooked to the network.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

CFML code (.cfm, and .cfc files) can be edited in any text editor including Notepad.  Adobe has an official IDE called ColdFusion Builder.  A lot of developers simply use Sublime Text or even Dreamweaver.

CFML is compiled by a just-in-time compiler so you just need to edit the code and then you can refresh the page.  If you don't have a dev server, you can install CF locally with a copy of the code on your PC.

I would recommend your company hire someone (or another company) with experience in CF to help you manage the code.

Comment: I agree with every part of this answer except actual developers editing in Dreamweaver.

Comment: Thanks Brad,  Unfortunately I work for a government agency and it would take months to get someone on board and for just a few unique applications they won't want to spring for that.  If I can't keep it going they don't want to keep it so some I'd like to keep if I can some can go away.  Thanks for your help tho,

Comment: It's not the software you use, it's how you use it that counts.  I do my unix work in vi and my ColdFusion work in Dreamweaver.

Comment: Thanks Dan.  I'll have to think about Dreamweaver if it will be of value for what we've decided to try to keep going or not.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest brackets.io. It has a coldfusion plugin so does code hinting. this is extremely helpful if you don't have too much knowledge of the language.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Flash Builder 4.6 for Coldfusion 9,10 and Flex MX . If I'm not wrong, you will be needing it to develop Flex/Coldfusion solutions. So your Adobe Flex Builder 2 CD might be handy if you have to support those kind of applications.